# MDADM Nvme raid Slower than traditional HDD, need enlightenment

Tags: linux, centos, hard-disk, software-raid, nvme

I have setup server about 20 days ago with new nvme, before setup raid mdadm the two Nvme samsung 980 pro 1TB i test bench have IO speed average 1.5G/s each nvme, but after creating raid 1, IO nvme only about 70mb/s. and still fast traditional HDD on my laptop which goes up to 120mb/s. Drive health 100% since new.

Format EXT4

Result bench.sh https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHHFR.png

```
[root@id1 var]# wget -qO- bench.sh | bash
-------------------- A Bench.sh Script By Teddysun -------------------
 Version            : v2022-06-01
 Usage              : wget -qO- bench.sh | bash
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 CPU Model          : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU v4 @ 3.60GHz
 CPU Cores          : 12 @ 3799.703 MHz
 CPU Cache          : 15360 KB
 AES-NI             : Enabled
 VM-x/AMD-V         : Enabled
 Total Disk         : 6.2 TB (1.1 TB Used)
 Total Mem          : 93.9 GB (33.5 GB Used)
 Load average       : 2.75, 3.67, 4.10
 OS                 : CloudLinux release 8.6 (Leonid Kadenyuk)
 Arch               : x86_64 (64 Bit)
 Kernel             : 4.18.0-372.19.1.lve.el8.x86_64
 TCP CC             : cubic
 Virtualization     : Dedicated

----------------------------------------------------------------------
 I/O Speed(1st run) : 78.0 MB/s
 I/O Speed(2nd run) : 78.0 MB/s
 I/O Speed(3rd run) : 78.0 MB/s
 I/O Speed(average) : 78.0 MB/s
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From mdadm detail

```
[root@node1 ~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md126
/dev/md126:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Sep 21 07:23:19 2022
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 964901888 (920.20 GiB 988.06 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 964901888 (920.20 GiB 988.06 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Sun Oct  2 11:55:36 2022
             State : active
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : iclnm.com:root
              UUID : aca6bf5e:5d4e7cc0:036c9b46:uyc9h8u
            Events : 1332

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     259        4        0      active sync   /dev/nvme0n1p3
       1     259        7        1      active sync   /dev/nvme1n1p3
```

Result from mdstat

[root@node1 ~]# cat /proc/mdstat

```
Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md123 : active raid5 sde2[3] sdd2[1] sdb2[0]
      48857088 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      bitmap: 1/1 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

md124 : active raid5 sde1[3] sdd1[1] sdb1[0]
      1884835840 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      bitmap: 7/8 pages [28KB], 65536KB chunk

md125 : active raid1 nvme0n1p2[0] nvme1n1p2[1]
      1953728 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md126 : active raid1 nvme1n1p3[1] nvme0n1p3[0]
      964901888 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 2/8 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

md127 : active raid1 nvme1n1p1[1] nvme0n1p1[0]
      9763840 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Nvme mounted to /

Other SSD raid mounted on /home, above test run in / and other than home partition.

This is my first time using soft raid on linux and I don't understand if mdadm can't use Nvme drive or there is an error in the configuration. I made normal raid1 in general. I'm hoping someone can shed some light on the linux mdadm raid. I'm using almalinux 8.6

Comment: Units please. Is G/s actually GB/s or Gb/s? What is mb/s? It's really important to get the units right

Comment: Crosspost https://serverfault.com/questions/1112062/mdadm-nvme-raid-slower-than-traditional-hdd-need-enlightenment